# How do I create an alter replace in Oracle SQL with dynamic data?

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

I am creating an SQL file that will be ran automatically by a shell script and I want all the name(s) changed automatically.

**Current data for NAME (of datafiles)**

```
/oradata/dr4/<site_name>/scion/images09.dbf
/oradata/dr4/<site_name>/scion/images10.dbf
```

***METHOD #1:***

The loop below is what I have. The &1 is a variable with the SITE_NAME coming from the shell script:

```
 begin
for i in
(select 'alter database rename file
    '''||name||''' to '''||replace(name,'/oradata/dr4/&1/scion/%','/oradata/devdb12c/scion/%')||''''
 as cmd
from v$datafile
where name like '/oradata/dr4/&1/scion/%')
loop
execute immediate i.cmd;
end loop;
end;
/
```

***METHOD#2:***

```
----Change the names for those datafiles in v$datafile
SELECT name REPLACE(NAME,'dr4/&1','devdb12c') AS CUNION FROM v$datafile;
```

The method had to be in a loop but I had come close in METHOD#2. It was similar to something I did with another file for SED.

**The result is:**

```
old   4:     '''||name||''' to '''||replace(name,'/oradata/dr4/&1/scion/%','/oradata/devdb12c/scion/%')||''''
new   4:     '''||name||''' to '''||replace(name,'/oradata/dr4/<site_name>/scion/%','/oradata/devdb12c/scion/%')||''''
old   7: where name like '/oradata/dr4/&1/scion/us%')
new   7: where name like '/oradata/dr4/<site_name>/scion/us%')
```

**Expected output:**

```
/oradata/devdb12c/scion/images09.dbf
/oradata/devdb12c/scion/images10.dbf
/oradata/devdb12c/scion/users05.dbf
```

Comment: I will be easy to understand your question, if you could also add expected output along

Comment: Derp! Added the missing expected output.

Comment: Could your post `name` column sample data ?

Comment: @Ravi The _name_ is already mentioned above "/oradata/dr4/dublin/scion/images09.dbf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in `name` column consists

```
/oradata/dr4/<site_name>/scion/images09.dbf
```

And, your expected output is

```
/oradata/devdb12c/scion/images09.dbf
```

Then, you can simply replace `/dr4/<site_name>/` to `/devdb12c/`

**[>>>Demo Link<<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/213b2b/2)**

Comment: Yes, I used this in the end:`begin
for i in
(select 'alter database rename file
    '''||name||''' to '''||replace(name,'/dr4/&1/','/devdb12c/')||''''
 as cmd
from v$datafile
where name like '/oradata/dr4/&1/scion/%')
loop
execute immediate i.cmd;
end loop;
end;
/`

Answer (score 0):

SET VERIFY OFF is the answer.

i.e.

```
SET VERIFY OFF
     begin
    for i in
    (select 'alter database rename file
        '''||name||''' to '''||replace(name,'/oradata/dr4/&1/scion/%','/oradata/devdb12c/scion/%')||''''
     as cmd
    from v$datafile
    where name like '/oradata/dr4/&1/scion/%')
    loop
    execute immediate i.cmd;
    end loop;
    end;
    /
```